# Get Clang AST from C/C++ Code with Undeclared Identifiers

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I would like to generate an AST from a set of C/C++ code in which I know that there will be missing includes. Here is a sample.

```cpp
int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!");
}
```

I've tried doing this with  `clang -Xclang -ast-dump -fsyntax-only test.cpp`. But it stops exporting the AST when it encounters `printf`.

**With Import**

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!");
}
```

```
-FunctionDecl 0x1902628 <test.cpp:3:1, line:5:1> line:3:5 main 'int ()'
 `-CompoundStmt 0x20d6880 <col:12, line:5:1>
    `-CallExpr 0x20d6840 <line:4:2, col:24> 'int'
      |-ImplicitCastExpr 0x20d6828 <col:2> 'int (*)(const char *__restrict, ...)' <FunctionToPointerDecay>
      | `-DeclRefExpr 0x20d67b0 <col:2> 'int (const char *__restrict, ...)' lvalue Function 0x20c2808 'printf' 'int (const char *__restrict, ...)'
      `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x20d6868 <col:9> 'const char *' <ArrayToPointerDecay>
        `-StringLiteral 0x20d6788 <col:9> 'const char [14]' lvalue "Hello, World!"
```

**Without Import**

```
`-FunctionDecl 0xc71350 <test.cpp:3:1, line:5:1> line:3:5 main 'int ()'
  `-CompoundStmt 0xc71588 <col:12, line:5:1>
```

Comment: @Frank I've included examples, clang *does* stop exporting the AST on `printf`. Even though it should theoretically be able to continue.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. Can you please also add the full listing of the "with import" version of the code please.

Comment: @Frank updated. It does appear that `CompoundStatement` is how clang is handling this. But that's very uninformative. It may just be there because of the error.

Comment: As a quick sidenote, *import* is slightly misleading here as there's an actual feature called import being introduced in the language which means something else . The correct term here would have been "include the header" or "forward-declare the function".

Comment: @Frank python ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could reproduce your issue with clang-10, but as of clang-11.0, the output is much more informative and spits out an `UnresolvedLookupExpr` node as I'd expect:

```
FunctionDecl 0x5641ea7ce5d8 <<source>:9:1, line:11:1> line:9:5 main 'int ()'
  `-CompoundStmt 0x5641ea7ce860 <col:12, line:11:1>
    `-RecoveryExpr 0x5641ea7ce830 <line:10:5, col:27> '<dependent type>' contains-errors lvalue
      |-UnresolvedLookupExpr 0x5641ea7ce6f8 <col:5> '<overloaded function type>' lvalue (ADL) = 'printf' empty
      `-StringLiteral 0x5641ea7ce7c0 <col:12> 'const char [14]' lvalue "Hello, World!"
```

See on godbolt: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1v6h7rarc

So the fix is simply to use a more recent version of clang.